# How to merge my arrays for DB insertion?

Tags: php

I have 2 associative arrays.

```
Array ( [title1] => test1 [title2] => test2 [title3] => test3 )
```

and

```
 Array ( [image1] => images1.jpeg [image2] => images2.jpg [image3] => images3.png )
```

I want to insert each title and image name into database columns(image title and image name).

How it is possible? Anyway to merge them and after that do insertion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$finalArray = array();
// Use min to avoid improper "OutOfBounds"
$lengthOfArray = min(count($array1), count($array2));

for(i = 1; i <= $lengthOfArray; $i++) {
   array_push($finalArray,
       array(
         'title' => $array1['title' + $i],
         'image' => $array2['image' + $i]
       )
   );
}
```

With this, in your finalArray you will have tuples of title an image for every database entry.

Comment: Don't use `count` in the `for`, save it into a variable previously, so the array will not be counted on every iteration.

Comment: @bazmegakapa of course you are right :-) The code should show the "idea" and was not ment to be completely perfect ^^

Comment: that's true. But be aware of the responsibility that a lot of newcomers just copy and paste these codes. I'm not talking about the OP only, but also everyone who finds our answers by searching. If you allow me, I will change this bit in your code.

Comment: @bazmegakapa happy that we're clear :-) I changed the code by myself, thank you for the advice

Answer (score 2):

Look at [array_combine()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)

Comment: Could you provide an example on how will this help the OP to achieve what he wanted?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe instead of combining the arrays, you can use a foreach to construct your query from the two arrays:

```
//ARRAYS
$a1=array('title1' => 'test1','title2' => 'test2','title3' => 'test3',);
$a2=array('image1' => 'images1.jpeg', 'image2' => 'images2.jpg', 'image3' => 'images3.png');

$fos=''; //we will collect values into this string
foreach ($a1 as $k=>$v) { //we iterate through the first array
    $k2=substr($k, 5);  //we get the number from the array key (like 2 from title2)
    $fos.=empty($fos) ? '' : ', '; //adding commas when needed
    $fos.="('{$v}', '{$a2['image'.$k2]}')"; //adding the right values to the values string
}

$q="insert into images (title, filename) values $fos"; //and finishing up the query
```

In this case the constructed query will be like:

```
insert into images (title, filename) values 
('test1', 'images1.jpeg'), 
('test2', 'images2.jpg'), 
('test3', 'images3.png')
```

**Note**: of course array values need to be correctly escaped for DB usage

Answer (score -1):

```
array_merge($array1, $array2);
```